# Can I use ASP.NET Session[] variable in an external DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state, session-variables

I have two projects, the DLL project which has all my logic and data access stuff, and the ASP.NET project which does my forms etc.

I am a bit confused.  I thought if I added the System.Web namespace reference to the DLL project I would be able to reference the Session state information of the ASP.NET page.

I could use each page to get the session info out and pass it to the DLL for the processing but would love to be able to process things directly from the DLL class(s).

Is this possible?

I have fiddled with the System.Web namespace and just seem able to get a reference to the Session variable.

Thanks all.

Jon

Comment: Thank you everyone.  I have decided to keep things separate.  I already had an interface for any of the objects to be put into the Session so I will pull out the Session data in the page and then pass it to my Business Logic.  I agree this could then be used in different situations.  Thx all! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to use HttpContext.Current.Session

## Edit

While yes I agree you should not tightly couple your Business Logic DAL or etc assemblies to ASP.Net session. There are plenty of valid cases for accessing HTTP Context outside of a web project.

Web Controls is probably one of the best examples, reusable HTTP modules, etc..

Now one option, if you want to have your DLL pull the stuff from Session, is to abstract out session. So you could define an interface like IStorage, that your library will know how to use. Then you can have a SessionStorage or MemoryStorage class and use IoC to inject the appropriate class into your library classes. This gives you the freedom to code it how you wanted it to be coded without tying your code to Session. Oh and one other benefit if done properly can be used to not tie your code to the session on the web either.

Comment: Thank you for the info, it answered the question perfectly... but as Tom said I think it is best if I do not tightly couple them.  But you hit the nail on the head as far as my question.

Answer (score 11):

As long as the Assembly is loaded in the scope of the Session, it will have access.

Although this type of tight coupling isn't really recommended.

Comment: thank you for the comment about not recommending it.  I will go with teh page referencing it and let the DLL just do the logic.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use HttpContext.Current.Session in your DLL but this is considered as bad practice. A better approach would be to pass the values stored in the session dictionary to your DLL instead of it referencing the session. Another benefit you will gain is that the code in your DLL won't be coupled to the ASP.NET runtime meaning it will be easier to test.

Answer (score 2):

As said by the others, you can always use HttpContext.Current.Session in your DLL, I assume it's your BAL, but you need to be really carefull.  What if your DLL is later consumed by a windows service, or some other app that doesn't have an HTTPContext?  Whenever I've done this it's always been in a property get method where I wrap the attempt to access HttpContext.Current.Session in a try catch block and if anything goes wrong I repull the needed data from the db.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use HttpContext.Current.Session as your dll will not run always with the Web Application. It may run with any other application like Windows,Console itc.

It is better to use a Method which is actully accept a parameter, which will come form Session Value, if you are using ASP.Net Application, otherwise there will not be any dependency of the application. If your dll project already developed and you are trying to modify the exsiting business logic then no, dont modify your exsiting method, use an Overload method.